# I have a Rails task: should I use script/runner or rake?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake

For *ad hoc* Rails tasks we have a few implementation alternatives, chief among which would seem to be:

```
script/runner some_useful_thing
```

and:

```
rake some:other_useful_thing
```

Which option should I prefer? If there's a clear favourite then when, if ever, should I consider using the other? If never, then why would you suppose it's still present in the framework without deprecation warnings?

Answer (score 64, accepted):

The difference between them is that `script/runner` boots Rails whereas a Rake task doesn't unless you tell it to by making the task depend on `:environment`, like this:

```
task :some_useful_task => :environment do
  # do some useful task
end
```

Since booting Rails is expensive, it might be worth skipping if you can avoid it.

Other than that, they are roughly equivalent. I use both, but lately I've used `script/runner` executing a script separately more.

Answer (score 10):

FWIW there seems to be some [movement away from using script runner](http://www.icyte.com/system/snapshots/fs1/6/2/8/d/628ddf1f6b7a231ddf6d0c9f0dc7e38dc7834e06/index.html) in favor of rake:

> Update (4/25/2009): I recommend using rake tasks as opposed to script/runner for recurring tasks.

Also, as [per this post](http://www.railsenvy.com/2007/6/11/ruby-on-rails-rake-tutorial#rails_models) you can use rake for recurring tasks just fine:

> If I then wanted this to run nightly on my production database at midnight, I might write a cronjob that looks something like this:
>
> > 0 0 * * * cd /var/www/apps/rails_app/ && /usr/local/bin/rake RAILS_ENV=production utils:send_expire_soon_emails

Comment: Your first link is dead, not sure whether the article has been removed or just the blog rearranged.

Comment: I'm not sure a single blog posts (which sadly does not explain it's reasons for it's rake-vs-runner claim) really counts as a movement.

Answer (score 10):

Passing parameters to a rake task is a pain in the butt, to say the least.  You either need to resort to environment variables or a very hackish parameter system that is not intuitive and has lots of caveats.

If your task needs to handle command line arguments gracefully then writing a script is the way to go.

Luke Francl mentions script/runner booting up Rails.  That's true.  But if you don't want to boot up rails then just run the script as is without script/runner.  So the only real difference between scripts and rake tasks are their aesthetics.  Choose whatever feels right to you.

I use rake tasks for little tasks (one or two lines).  Anything more complicated goes into the script/ directory.  I'll break this rule if I think other developers will expect the code to live in one place over another.

Answer (score 9):

Corrected based on comment 2 down. Give them the karma!

FWIW - Rails 3.0+ changes how you initialize the Rails system in a standalone script.

```
require File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/config/environment'
```

As mentioned above you can also do:

```
rails runner script/<script name>
```

Or put all the code in a Rake task, but I have a lot of legacy code from Rails 2; so I didn't want to go down that path immediately.

Each has its advantages and disadvantages.

Answer (score 5):

One thing I've done is just write normal ruby scripts and put them in the `script/maintenance` directory.

All you need to do to load rails and get access to all your models, etc, is put `require '../../config/environment.rb'` at the top of your file, then you're away.

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to put these into rake tasks?

Comment: Why bother with the added complexity of a rake task. This way we just have a file that can get run like any other script on a *nix system

Comment: ^^ to clarify: Rake is great, and I'd use it if you needed dependencies, etc, but if you don't, it's just one more thing to think about for no reason

Comment: And than you upgrade rails version, and the "private" detail of the location of environment.rb needs to be managed.

Answer (score 3):

For one off commands script/runner can be fine. For anything repeated, a rake task is easier in the long-run, and has a summary if you forget what it does.

Answer (score 3):

In Rails 3.0+, the `config/environment.rb` requires the `config/application.rb`, that requires the `config/boot.rb`.

So, to load an app in Rails 3, you still only have to require the `environment.rb`

Answer (score 2):

I got the impression script/runner was primarily for periodic tasks.  E.g., a cron job that runs:

```
SomeClass.update_from_web('http://www.sourcefordata.gov/')
```

Comment: Nothing I've seen about a `runner` task requires or implies that it is for cron jobs primarily. Instead, I consider runner for tasks that have no need of the Rails presentation layer but want access to the DB and models, and that I wouldn't put into a controller or model because it makes no sense to put it there.