# how do you convert a separate Ruby program into a rake task?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Sorry for what seems like a basic question, but I'm stumped.

I have a Rails app that relies in part on third party data that I download periodically (generally daily) and integrate into the app's database.  The Ruby code that I use to get the third party data is in separate Ruby files, i.e., not integrated as code in any of my controllers.  So, I run these programs when needed via `rails runner program.rb` (probably not relevant, but all of them use the mechanize gem in gathering the third party data).

I want to try using Heroku's scheduler to make my data gathering more automated, and the recommendation for doing this is to set up rake tasks.  Is there a rake task equivalent for `rails runner program.rb`?

Thanks

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/591503/i-have-a-rails-task-should-i-use-script-runner-or-rake

Answer (score 0):

As far as converting a rails command into a rake task it's pretty easy, you just namespace it like this:

```
# /lib/tasks/my_task.rake
namespace :mytask do

  desc 'the description of your task'
  task :my_task => :environment do
    puts 'my task was executed'
  end
end
```

Then you'd call it with 'rake mytask:my_task' later on, which you should be able to do with Heroku's scheduler. Also I'd like to recommend the 'whenever' gem for setting things up on a schedule as I have no experience with Heroku but have found that gem to be fantastic.

Comment: My confusion is with how to execute the necessary code from the Ruby script without putting it all in the rake file.  Is there a way to do this?  Where you have "puts 'my task was executed'" I want to have my Ruby script execute . . . so, if it's in "program.rb" how do I reference it/get it to execute from within the rake file?

Comment: Ahhh ok. You're probably thinking of a "system" call. You'd do that as system('program.rb'). You also have the (better) option to either load or require it like: load('myfile.rb') or require('./my_file.rb') However I would recommend putting it in you rake task so it could be checked into your version control with the rest of your website. Possibly including a few extra libraries in /lib if you'd like to just call some classes in the rake task.