# Daemon vs Runner vs Rake Tasks vs Active Job

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xml, postgresql, background-process

I have a list of tasks that need to be performed in the background (Rails 5.0.1) in the following order-

1. Download a zip file
2. Extract the xml file from it (avg. size ~ 400 MB)
3. Parse(Nokogiri XML::reader) the xml file for records that meet certain constraints and if found, add them to database (postgres)
4. Retrieve some email addresses from database and send them email

This needs to be done everyday without any human input. Right now, I am using Rails runner to do all of that and scheduling it using cron ('Whenever' gem). So, is using '**runner**' the **right approach**? Is there a **less memory intensive** approach I can use, given that the frontend (admin panel) won't be accessed much? How about active job, rake, daemons etc?

Comment: Parsing the XML is going to be the bottleneck no matter how you schedule the job. If you want a less memory intensive approach then try to find something that does not involve parsing a 400mb XML file into memory.

Comment: @max I am currently using Nokogiri xml reader which doesn't load the xml into memory, but read lines sequentially, parsing nodes. Is there a better solution? Maybe splitting the xml file?

Answer (score 2):

. A rake task is just a bunch of code inside a namespace that is executed  via rake management tool

. `runner` runs Ruby code in the context of Rails non-interactively

. Daemon on the other hand is completely different thing than this two, you can check more about it here: http://daemons.rubyforge.org/

For your case it's best to use rake because it doesn't boot rails "unless you make it" (runner have to boot rails).

Another thing is rake is single threaded, so If you want to a single task to be done efficiently you can use rake, if you have multiple tasks you can make use of workers and tools like Sidekiq, Resque and Delayed jobs

Comment: But as the xml file is being parsed, it is updating the database with new records too. So, isn't that, I will have to boot rails (production env) anyways, if I use rake? How can I use rake with models available for updating?

Comment: I don't know your exact usecase, you may need to boot up Rails, but you can also keep all these records that needs to be updated in a separate job (via delayed jobs or Sidekiq). So you the rake task only takes the time of parsing. and the job being queued the only time taken is for the parsing only

Comment: Even though using rake task, it requires rails environment when accessing database via active record.  So, in this situation, runner and rake task is equivalent.  See https://stackoverflow.com/a/591912/921859